# Having trouble webscraping dish descriptions from Deliveroo site. Text from nodes outputs list consisting of ""

Tags: r, web-scraping, rstudio, rvest

I'm trying to webscrape dish name, description and price info from Deliveroo's website here: https://deliveroo.co.uk/menu/aberdeen/aberdeen-city-centre/ask-italian-aberdeen . The issues I'm having is that when i try to extract the dish descriptions it only gives a list of   "".

I'm using the rvest package with the SelectorGadget but i guess its not getting the correct node. Inspecting the webpage it seems the information i want is kept here:

```html
*span data-reactid=".15qcr32ig3k.3.7.0.4:$626142.2.$4718552.$menuItemContent.1.0.0.$0" class="">Large green nocellara olives from Sicily.&nbsp;·&nbsp;£3.25</span>*
```

so i think its the "data-reactid" thing which is causing an issue.

```r
read_html("https://deliveroo.co.uk/menu/aberdeen/aberdeen-city-centre/ask-italian-aberdeen") %>% 
              html_nodes(".menu-index-page__item-desc") %>%
              html_text()
```

The output of this code is :

```r
[1] "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""
 [40] "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""
 [79] "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""
[118] "" "" "" "" ""
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think you can't do it using `rvest` alone because description part is generated via JavaScript. I would recommend using `splashr` or `Rselenium`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for overhead of selenium. All info is in json format within a `script` tag. Just extract that, parse with jsonlite library then pull out the menu items dataframe

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
library(jsonlite)

data <- jsonlite::fromJSON(read_html('https://deliveroo.co.uk/menu/aberdeen/aberdeen-city-centre/ask-italian-aberdeen') %>% 
                             html_node('[data-dom-id="app-element"]') %>%
                             html_text())
menu_items <- data$menu$items
View(menu_items)
```

---

**Sample view:**

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

As Mislav had suggested, you have only two options to do this, splashr or RSelenium. I have tried to address your question using RSelenium.

```
library(RSelenium)

# Check your chrome version and update as needed
rd <- rsDriver(browser = c("chrome"),chromever = "76.0.3809.126", check = FALSE, verbose = FALSE)

remdr <- rd$client

remdr$navigate("https://deliveroo.co.uk/menu/aberdeen/aberdeen-city-centre/ask-italian-aberdeen")
```

This would open up a new instance of Chrome and navigate to the provided URL. The particular website uses captcha to prevent bots and might not work well with our code. You have two options now.

> 1. You can manually input the captcha in the automated chrome instance and proceed.
> 2. You can open up the website normally, save the webpage completely and pass the local directory of the .html file to **remdr$navigate** function.

Once the website loads, run the below code to generate the complete list of items with it's description and price.

```
# A tiny function to get the texts from the fetched title elements
getText <- function(a){a$getElementText()[[1]]}

# Get title of items
titles = remdr$findElements(using = "class", value = "menu-index-page__item-title")
DishTitles <- unlist(lapply(titles,getText))


# Two other functions to get description and price from the fetched elements
getDesc <- function(a){
ifelse(length(strsplit(a$getElementText()[[1]]," · ",fixed=TRUE)[[1]])>1,
gsub("\n"," ",strsplit(a$getElementText()[[1]]," · ",fixed=TRUE)[[1]][1]),"Not available")
}
getPrice <- function(a){
ifelse(length(strsplit(a$getElementText()[[1]]," · ",fixed=TRUE)[[1]])>1,
gsub("\n"," ",strsplit(a$getElementText()[[1]]," · ",fixed=TRUE)[[1]][2]),
gsub("\n"," ",strsplit(a$getElementText()[[1]]," · ",fixed=TRUE)[[1]][1]))
}

# Get description and price
descandprice <-  remdr$findElements(using = "class", value = "menu-index-page__item-desc")
DishDescriptions <- unlist(lapply(descandprice,getDesc))
DishPrices <-  unlist(lapply(descandprice,getPrice))

# Create your menu data frame

Menu <- data.frame(Title = DishTitle,Description = DishDescriptions,Price = DishPrices, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

[image: Menu Dataframe]

I noticed that for a couple of items in the website, you do not have descriptions available. For these items, I have set the function to return the string 'Not available'. You can change it if you like.

Hope this helps!